# How to make a dynamic php webpage in a specific url?

Tags: php, redirect, routes

How to make a dynamic php webpage in a specific url? I.e.:

If I visit a facebook page of a person who have not verified his unique username so his profile shows in the url bar https://www.facebook.com/#!/profile.php?id=2..........6&fref=ts (when viewed as a logged in user) and http://www.facebook.com/people/username-something/2............6 (when viewed as a non logged in  user) but for some people in the url bar if i paste their url id with verified usename i.e- http://www.facebok.com/someusername it shows their profile.

So my question is: if I want to make something similar for my website for registered users how to do this as php grabs values from id but it (www.facebok.com/someusername) is just plain link? How php works here in the browser?

Comment: It is routing. A simple way is, write a .htaccess file for the routes. There are tons of example here. Make a search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey man it is done by editing your .htaccess file. I can give you the link of its tutorial :

[This is The Link Enjoy](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example php do it

Do not forget to set. httaccess to ignore the request, for example like this

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] =='somerequest'){
    //do something here

    } else {

    // do something if else
    }
    ?>
```

This is an example. htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```